# How to make JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat sleep

Tags: javascript, sleep, acrobat

I'm trying to get JavaScript to sleep in acrobat. I'm running

```
this.saveAs(saveFileName);
```

and it takes time to save the file but JavaScript keeps running and blows up later code.

Comment: Javascript is like a shark. It never sleeps. Try looking into doing whatever you're doing asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when saving file the later code cannot see the file fully downloaded. All I had to do is close the file and reopen the file and the later code ran ok.